# LINQ - IQueryable multiple where condition

Tags: performance, entity-framework, linq

I need to add 1 extra condition in where based on the if-else condition, but the code gets redundant. Please help to create a common query.

```
if (isFailure)
{
    var result = (from account in context.Account
                  join filetrans in context.FILE_TRANSACTION on account.ACCOUNTID equals filetrans.ACNT_ID
                  where accountIds.Contains(account.ACCOUNTID) && filetrans.PROCESS_STRT_TIME >= fromDateFilter && filetrans.PROCESS_STRT_TIME <= toDateFilter **&& failureStatus.Contains((decimal)filetrans.CRNT_FILE_STATUS_ID)**
                  select new
                              {
                                  account.ACCOUNTINFO,
                                  filetrans.ACNT_ID,
                                  filetrans.FILE_TRANID,
                                  filetrans.FILE_NM,
                                  filetrans.PROCESS_STRT_TIME,
                                  filetrans.CRNT_FILE_STATUS_ID
                              } )
                    .OrderByDescending(o => o.PROCESS_STRT_TIME)
                    .Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();                   
}
else
{
    var result = (from account in context.Account
                  join filetrans in context.AFRS_FILE_TRANSACTION on account.ACCOUNTID equals filetrans.ACNT_ID
                  where accountIds.Contains(account.ACCOUNTID) && filetrans.PROCESS_STRT_TIME >= fromDateFilter && filetrans.PROCESS_STRT_TIME <= toDateFilter
                  select new
                              {
                                  account.ACCOUNTINFO,
                                  filetrans.ACNT_ID,
                                  filetrans.FILE_TRANID,
                                  filetrans.FILE_NM,
                                  filetrans.PROCESS_STRT_TIME,
                                  filetrans.CRNT_FILE_STATUS_ID
                              })
                      .OrderByDescending(o => o.PROCESS_STRT_TIME)
                      .Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();                   
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend not generelizing, because linq handle function delegates inefficiently it is best to keep the entire expression, otherwise if hte cardinality of the entity is small enough, you can consider using the func delegate, though keep in mind when using a func for the where clause it will resolve the entire list and execute the function sequentially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main benefit of LINQ that queries can be composed. Extract common part and apply needed filters later.

```cs
var query =
    from account in context.Account
    join filetrans in context.FILE_TRANSACTION on account.ACCOUNTID equals filetrans.ACNT_ID
    where accountIds.Contains(account.ACCOUNTID) && 
        filetrans.PROCESS_STRT_TIME >= fromDateFilter && 
        filetrans.PROCESS_STRT_TIME <= toDateFilter
    select new { account, filetrans };

if (isFailure)
{
    query = query.Where(x => failureStatus.Contains((decimal)x.filetrans.CRNT_FILE_STATUS_ID))
}

var result = query
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        x.account.ACCOUNTINFO,
        x.filetrans.ACNT_ID,
        x.filetrans.FILE_TRANID,
        x.filetrans.FILE_NM,
        x.filetrans.PROCESS_STRT_TIME,
        x.filetrans.CRNT_FILE_STATUS_ID
    })
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.PROCESS_STRT_TIME)
    .Skip(skip).Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: what if I want to select a few columns from account & filetrans ? Please check the modified question

Comment: @VMK, updated answer.